# Unicode or font support for an embedded project

Tags: design, embedded-systems, fonts

I am working on an project for development of an Embedded system with following requirements.

1. Should be able to receive a text in English language from a Host device. Interfaced over Modbus.
2. Should be able to convert a given text into a bit pattern which would be later processed to be displayed on a fixed-dimension LED matrix.
3. Based on certain other conditions set by Host, this device should be able to convert the text into a pre-defined set of local languages.
4. No constraint on whether it has to be an Embedded Linux and/or a RTOS-based solution. Either ways, anything open-source is preferable.
5. Must be a freescale-based design. (Freescale is NXP)

The third requirement in the list above is what I am worried about.
Font support for local languages without a library is what concerns me.

What I have thought of doing:

1. Check if there is an Embedded linux which has support for .ttf files.
2. If yes, check if it can ported to a freescale microcontroller.
3. Develop a driver for getting data over Modbus.
4. Process the received data using .ttf and get a binary output (.bin)
5. Use the .bin file to process it as per LED matrix

The other approach could be: (This is unlikely to be accepted by mamangement)

1. Let the fonts processing be done at Host, which is also an embedded system.
2. Develop a typical non-OS based firmware to receive the processed .bin file as data on Modbus. Or further convenient, get an actual data pattern to be dumped on LED matrix.

The other lame approach could be:

1. Fonts processing for different languages using a computer is already a proven concept. An operator with a computer can generate all possible texts to be displayed for all required languages and convert that into a .bin file. Using a media (Either USB or Modbus) that .bin can be transferred to all devices. This would be a one-time process unless the data needs to be changed.
2. Device has NAND/NOR flash-based memory to store .bin files.

How feasible is it as an idea to do it based on an Embedded Linux with fonts processing?